# Let $A$ be a square matrix of order n such that ∃m ∈ N such that $A^m$ = 0. Then...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, nilpotence

Then.

1) The only eigenvalue (complex) of $A$ is $0$ and then $\text{tr}(A)=0$.

2) $\text{tr} (A) = 0$ but $A$ can have complex eigenvalues $ \ne 0$.

3) We can deduce that $\det(A)=0$ but not $\text{tr}(A)=0$.

Only one of those is true but I really don't know how to start, I've tried to write a generic matrix $3 \times 3$ and imposing $A^2=0$ but this method is obviously long, dumb and not generic...

Comment: The answer depends on which results you have learned and are allowed to use.

Comment: Do you know about annihilating and minimal polynomials?

Comment: well, i know that if i have a complex eigenvalue i also have his conjugate as a root of the characteristic polynomial of A...    ...so if "2)" is true i will have 2 complex numbers on the diagonal of the matrix "$D$"...

Comment: @PrasunBiswas i know what minimal polynomials are. I dont know about Jordan's forms.

Comment: In that case, note that $x^m$ is an annihilating polynomial for $A$ (more precisely the matrix transformation $\bf x\mapsto A\bf x$) from which we conclude that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x$ which has $0$ as the only root/eigenvalue. Furthermore, since $\textrm{Tr}(A)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$, we also have $\textrm{Tr}(A)=0$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Hum...  ...why can i say that?

Comment: Can you precisely point out which part of my argument are you stuck at?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas it was all about my bad relationship with the definition of minimal polynomials...

Comment: @PrasunBiswas ..$(x^m)(A)=0$  is pretty incomprehensible for me... ... finally i got it, is $A^m$ where just like $p(x)=3x$ so $p(A)=3A$.

Comment: Minimal and/or characteristic polynomials are not necessary here.  See my answer.

Comment: I made a minor edit to your question, repalcing "\ =" with "\ne",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question may be answered quite simply from first principles without the machinery of characteristic or minimal polynomials, to wit:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$; then

$A\vec v = \lambda \vec v \tag 1$

for some vector $\vec v \ne 0$.  It follows that

$A^2 \vec v = A(A\vec v) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda A\vec v = \lambda^2 \vec v; \tag 2$

if

$A^k \vec v = \lambda^k \vec v, \tag 3$

then

$A^{k + 1} \vec v = A(A^k \vec v) = A\lambda^k \vec v = \lambda^k A \vec v = \lambda^k \lambda \vec v = \lambda^{k + 1} \vec v; \tag 4$

we have just shown by induction that

$A^q \vec v = \lambda^q \vec v \tag 5$

for every integer $q \ge 1$; therefore, since

$A^m = 0, \tag 6$

it follows that

$\lambda^m \vec v = A^m \vec v = 0, \tag 7$

and since $\vec v \ne 0$, we find

$\lambda^m = 0, \tag 8$

forcing

$\lambda = 0. \tag{9}$

We see that every eigenvalue of $A$ is zero, whence

$\text{tr}(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i = 0, \tag{10}$

where $\lambda_i$ ranges over the complete set of eigenvalues of $A$.  Thus we see that (1) binds but that (2) and (3) are false.

Incidentally, we also have

$(\det A)^m = \det A^m = 0, \tag{11}$

so

$\det A = 0 \tag{12}$

as well.

Comment: Damn cute. YAY :)

Comment: Glad to help out.

Comment: maybe one day i will be competent at least like you :|

Comment: A minor comment: It actually follows trivially that $\det A=0$ once we know that $0$ is one of the eigenvalues of $A$ because $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ (by definition).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas:  of course, but as I said I was trying to avoid the use of minimal/characteristic polynomials.  And actually, the *definition* of eigenvalue is that $A \vec v = \lambda \vec v$ for some $\vec v \ne 0$, *not* $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, the two definitions are equivalent. Assuming one implies the other. $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ iff there exists a **nontrivial** solution $\bf v$ for $(A-\lambda I)\bf v=0$, i.e., $A\bf v=\lambda \bf v$